# Нужно ли выделять запятыми оборот с предлогом "благодаря" и дополнениями?

Tags: запятая

Несмотря на гораздо более высокую стоимость, чем у арматуры из нержавеющей стали, благодаря высокой конкуренции и насыщенности рынка(,) титановую арматуру можно считать доступной.
Нужно ли здесь ставить запятую?

Comment: Такое предложение никакие знаки препинания не спасут, такое предложение надо переделывать. У него не только неудачная грамматика, но и  смысл непонятен. Ясно одно: титан стоит дороже. Почему при этом он доступен, причем тут конкуренция и насыщенность рынка? Предложение нужно строить так, чтобы его понял даже неспециалист.

Answer (score 1):

Дополнения с предлогом "благодаря" не обособляются, если они не распространены (Сделал работу благодаря мне). В данном случае, наоборот, конструкция состоит из нескольких слов, поэтому запятая нужна.

Comment: Спасибо большое.

Answer (score 1):

А "несмотря" и "благодаря" в одном предложении - это ничего? Это кашшшмар. Какие уж тут тонкости с запятыми...

По существу вопроса: активно не советую ставить запятую. Не так уж распространен этот оборот с "благодаря", его граница и без запятой видна. Так что оснований для постановки нет.

Answer (score 0):

Запятая в любом случае ставится хотя бы из-за слова *Несмотря*. Да, ещё нужно выделить разграничение конструкции с *благодаря*, поэтому запятая, бесспорно, нужна.

Answer (score 0):

Запятая не нужна. Обороты с *благодаря* обособляются факультативно.

Основные факторы постановки факультативных запятых при оборотах с предлогами:

1.Распространенность оборота - этого нет.

2.Позиция между словами с сильной синтаксической связью - нет.

3.Причинное значение - нет.

4.Значение уточнения - нет.

http://gramota.ru/spravka/punctum/punctum_attach1/